# catch shift-click events in ol.interaction.Draw Open Layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to use `ol.interaction.Draw` to add polygons to an openlayers map. I also have a Snap interaction on, and set up to turn off while I'm holding down shift.

```
const
  snapInteraction = new ol.interaction.Snap({
    source: drawLayer.getSource()
  }),
  turnOnSnap = (evt) => {
    if (!isShiftKey(evt)) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('shift key is down, turning off snap');
    snapInteraction.setActive(false);
  },
  turnOffSnap = (evt) => {
    if (!isShiftKey(evt)) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('shift key is up, turning on snap');
    snapInteraction.setActive(true);
  };

document.addEventListener('keydown', turnOnSnap);
document.addEventListener('keyup', turnOffSnap);
```

This works to disable snapping. However, my Draw interaction doesn't work when I hold down shift. I know that the `condition` parameter defaults to `ol.events.condition.noModifierKeys`, but when I make a custom `condition` it never even gets hit!

```
const drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: drawLayer.getSource(),
  type: 'Polygon',
  condition: function (evt) {
    console.log("yo, why isn't this hit when I hold down shift?", evt);
    return (ol.events.condition.noModifierKeys(evt) ||
      ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(evt));
  }
});
```

Why is the drawInteraction ignoring the shift+click events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for `freehandCondition` is catching shift+click events, so they never get evaluated for `condition`. Change that to something else, and the shift+click events will hit your custom condition function.

```
const drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: drawLayer.getSource(),
  type: 'Polygon',
  condition: function (evt) {
    return (ol.events.condition.noModifierKeys(evt) ||
      ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(evt));
  },
  freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.never, // <-- add this line
});
```